# How to place image on part of other image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to place image of pawn on part of other image of a pawn but when I am trying to do it it puts the pawns near the previous pawn:
[image]

This is what I **want** to have:
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<td class="" row="0" col="0"><span>1</span>
<img class="soldiers" playernumber="1" soldiernumber="1" src="Resources/images/player_1.png">
<img class="soldiers" playernumber="1" soldiernumber="2" src="Resources/images/player_1.png">
<img class="soldiers" playernumber="1" soldiernumber="3" src="Resources/images/player_1.png">
<img class="soldiers" playernumber="1" soldiernumber="4" src="Resources/images/player_1.png">
<img class="soldiers" playernumber="2" soldiernumber="1" src="Resources/images/player_2.png">
<img class="soldiers" playernumber="2" soldiernumber="2" src="Resources/images/player_2.png">
<img class="soldiers" playernumber="2" soldiernumber="3" src="Resources/images/player_2.png">
<img class="soldiers" playernumber="2" soldiernumber="4" src="Resources/images/player_2.png">
</td>
```

**CSS:**

```
td {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.soldiers
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

td span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to use the absolute positioning with the .soldiers class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've prepared a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgge3gph/2) demonstrating what you intend.

```
$(function(){
    var s = 0;
    $('.soldiers').each(function(){
        $(this).css({'top':s,'left':s});
        s+=10;
    });
});
```

What's happening in the fiddle is I've added `position:absolute;` to the class .soldiers
and incremented (via jQuery each() method) a determined value (in this case 10) for `top` and `left`, to each .soldiers element.

You may also need to work with `z-index` to work layer positioning for the soldiers if you're moving pieces later on